# react-native-track-player hide notification

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio, react-native-track-player

i have a player where it will play 4 sound randomly

```
    export const startSound = async () => {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);

  await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
  await TrackPlayer.add({
    id: random,
    url: openingSound[random ? random : 1].sound,
  });

  await TrackPlayer.play();
};
```

when react-native-track-player play, it will have notification even when i didnt set anything except the sound. anyone know how to hide the notification when it play?

Comment: Were you able to fix this?